# How to set a tag at the experiment level in MLFlow

Tags: python, mlflow, mlops

I can see that an experiment in MLFlow can have tags (like runs can have tags).
I'm able to set a run's tag using `mlflow.set_tag`, but how do I set it for an experiment?

Comment: I see the rest API (https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#set-experiment-tag), i'm trying to set it from Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the Python API, the very [first example](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html) in `mlflow.tracking package` that shows how to create the `MLflowClient` is really showing how to tag experiment using the `client.set_experiment_tag` function ([doc](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.set_experiment_tag)):

```py
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

# Create an experiment with a name that is unique and case sensitive.
client = MlflowClient()
experiment_id = client.create_experiment("Social NLP Experiments")
client.set_experiment_tag(experiment_id, "nlp.framework", "Spark NLP")
```

you can also set it for model version with [set_model_version_tag](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html#mlflow.client.MlflowClient.set_model_version_tag) function, and for registered model with [set_registered_model_tag](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.set_registered_model_tag).

Comment: As of Sep 23, 2022, all links appear to be broken.

Comment: fixed - they moved `MLflowClient` into a separate package. Thank you for reporting

Answer (score 0):

While the client is very flexible, you can **set tags at experiments with mlflow alone**.

For instance, this is how to set a description visible in UI:

```
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name=EXPERIMENT_NAME)
mlflow.set_experiment_tag('mlflow.note.content',EXPERIMENT_DESCRIPTION)
```

[image]
NOTE: tested under `mlflow=2.3.2`.